# Transfer data from C# Class to XML File

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, datetime

I want to transfer a variable containing DateTime string to the XML file. Is there any way to access data from C# Class in XML File.

Here's my C# Code:

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.Today.AddHours(17);
string datetime = dt.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss");
```

Here's my XML Code where I need to access this data string:

```
<ProductLastModifiedDate>2020-02-21T09:00:00+05:30</ProductLastModifiedDate>
```

In the above XML Code I want to set dateTime retrieved from C# class file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use xml linq :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;
namespace XML
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            DateTime dt = DateTime.Today.AddHours(17);
            string datetime = dt.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss");

            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);

            XElement date = doc.Descendants("ProductLastModifiedDate").FirstOrDefault();
            date.SetValue(datetime);
            doc.Save(FILENAME);

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Another approach is using `XmlDocument`

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.Today.AddHours(17);
string datetime = dt.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss");

var xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
xmlDoc.Load(filePath);
xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("ProductLastModifiedDate").InnerText = datetime;            
xmlDoc.Save(filePath);
```

OUTPUT

```
<ProductLastModifiedDate>2020-02-20T17:00:00</ProductLastModifiedDate>
```